# 404.php to show in URL on error

Tags: php, wordpress

When I go to an incorrect URL on my Wordpress site the 404.php file displays. The problem is that when it displays I need it to go to http://..../404.php. As of right now the URL that was attempted to be accessed is what continues to show.

Comment: Why would you want to redirect your user to the 404 page itself?

Comment: The invalid URL will continue to show but WP should load the 404 template. What content are you seeing?

Comment: My client wants to /404.php to show for analytics purposes.